# Slide div into div, using transform

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, transform

I'm working on a sliding form in HTML. Basically I want that only one of the two (f1|f2) is visible in the Container. But I don't know how to hide the other div from being visible on the Page.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqu67yrw/

I already tried using `overflow: hidden;` that didn't work, because after the transformation the "new" overflow was still visible, but the old that wasn't overflowing anymore was still invisible.

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <form class="f1">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
          <input type="text" placeholder="F1" />
          <input id="SBB" type="button" value="Show other Panel" />
        </form>
        <form class="f2">
          <h1>dolor sit</h1>
          <input type="password" placeholder="F2" />
          <input id="FBB" type="button" value="Go back" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**style.scss**

```
.container {
  width: 33%;
  height: 10%;

  padding: 1rem;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;

  transform: translateX(15%);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  &.active {
    transform: translateX(-35%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}

.f1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.f2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

**core.js**

```
const secondBoxBtn = document.getElementById("SBB");
const firstBoxBtn = document.getElementById("FBB");
const container = document.getElementById("slide");

secondBoxBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.add("active");
});
firstBoxBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.remove("active");
});
```

I expect that f1/f2 slides from the border of the box into the center of it. And the other one slides out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes in css, and it works, check link

```js
const secondBoxBtn = document.getElementById("SBB");
const firstBoxBtn = document.getElementById("FBB");
const container = document.getElementById("slide");

secondBoxBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.add("active");
});
firstBoxBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
   white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1rem;
      

  &.active {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}

.f1 {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block
}

.f2 {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <form class="f1">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
          <input type="text" placeholder="F1" />
          <input id="SBB" type="button" value="Show other Panel" />
        </form>
        <form class="f2">
          <h1>dolor sit</h1>
          <input type="password" placeholder="F2" />
          <input id="FBB" type="button" value="Go back" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Aditya055/pen/pmrRoq